# Reduce time for OCR using tessaract

Tags: python, ocr, wrapper, python-tesseract

i am currently using pytessarct wrapper to extract text from image. my image may be rotated which i don't know so my approach till now is to call below ocr function for rotated image in loop.i want to know if there is some other wrapper or some method through which i can reduce my time significantly.
def ocr(image):
return pytesseract.image_to_string(
image,
lang="eng",
config="--psm 11 --oem 3"
)

I tried multithreading and it reduced some time. But still it is taking much time. I am looking for any other wrapper(may be of c++ that can be used in python) or some method to reduce time significantly.